# Add a Region for Slideshow in Zen

Tags: theming, javascript

I want to create a region for a slideshow using the Zen Theme. The problem is, I don't know where to place the code in the page.tpl.php file. I want the navigation to be ontop, followed by the slideshow, followed by the rest of the website. I've tried placing the following code everywhere in the page.tpl.php file, but have not been able to yield the desired result.

Here is the code I'm using:

```
  <?php if ($page['featured_slider']): ?>
    <div id="featured-slider">
      <?php print render($page['featured_slider']); ?>
    </div> <!-- End Featured Slider-->
  <?php endif; ?>
```

Here is the page.tpl.php file WITHOUT the above code:

```
?>

<div id="page-wrapper"><div id="page">

  <div id="header"><div class="section clearfix">

    <?php if ($logo): ?>
      <a href="<?php print $front_page; ?>" title="<?php print t('Home'); ?>" rel="home" id="logo"><img src="<?php print $logo; ?>" alt="<?php print t('Home'); ?>" /></a>
    <?php endif; ?>

    <?php if ($site_name || $site_slogan): ?>
      <div id="name-and-slogan">
        <?php if ($site_name): ?>
          <?php if ($title): ?>
            <div id="site-name"><strong>
              <a href="<?php print $front_page; ?>" title="<?php print t('Home'); ?>" rel="home"><span><?php print $site_name; ?></span></a>
            </strong></div>
          <?php else: /* Use h1 when the content title is empty */ ?>
            <h1 id="site-name">
              <a href="<?php print $front_page; ?>" title="<?php print t('Home'); ?>" rel="home"><span><?php print $site_name; ?></span></a>
            </h1>
          <?php endif; ?>
        <?php endif; ?>

        <?php if ($site_slogan): ?>
          <div id="site-slogan"><?php print $site_slogan; ?></div>
        <?php endif; ?>
      </div><!-- /#name-and-slogan -->
    <?php endif; ?>

    <?php print theme('links__system_secondary_menu', array(
      'links' => $secondary_menu,
      'attributes' => array(
        'id' => 'secondary-menu',
        'class' => array('links', 'inline', 'clearfix'),
      ),
      'heading' => array(
        'text' => $secondary_menu_heading,
        'level' => 'h2',
        'class' => array('element-invisible'),
      ),
    )); ?>

    <?php print render($page['header']); ?>

  </div></div><!-- /.section, /#header -->

  <div id="main-wrapper"><div id="main" class="clearfix<?php if ($main_menu || $page['navigation']) { print ' with-navigation'; } ?>">

    <div id="content" class="column"><div class="section">
      <?php print render($page['highlighted']); ?>
      <?php print $breadcrumb; ?>
      <a id="main-content"></a>
      <?php print render($title_prefix); ?>
      <?php if ($title): ?>
        <h1 class="title" id="page-title"><?php print $title; ?></h1>
      <?php endif; ?>
      <?php print render($title_suffix); ?>
      <?php print $messages; ?>
      <?php if ($tabs = render($tabs)): ?>
        <div class="tabs"><?php print $tabs; ?></div>
      <?php endif; ?>
      <?php print render($page['help']); ?>
      <?php if ($action_links): ?>
        <ul class="action-links"><?php print render($action_links); ?></ul>
      <?php endif; ?>
      <?php print render($page['content']); ?>
      <?php print $feed_icons; ?>
    </div></div><!-- /.section, /#content -->

    <?php if ($page['navigation'] || $main_menu): ?>
      <div id="navigation"><div class="section clearfix">

        <?php print theme('links__system_main_menu', array(
          'links' => $main_menu,
          'attributes' => array(
            'id' => 'main-menu',
            'class' => array('links', 'inline', 'clearfix'),
          ),
          'heading' => array(
            'text' => t('Main menu'),
            'level' => 'h2',
            'class' => array('element-invisible'),
          ),
        )); ?>

        <?php print render($page['navigation']); ?>

      </div></div><!-- /.section, /#navigation -->
    <?php endif; ?>

    <?php print render($page['sidebar_first']); ?>

    <?php print render($page['sidebar_second']); ?>

  </div></div><!-- /#main, /#main-wrapper -->

  <?php print render($page['footer']); ?>

</div></div><!-- /#page, /#page-wrapper -->

<?php print render($page['bottom']); ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try removing     `if($page['featured_slider']):`

Make sure you have placed your slideshow block in featured_slider region.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you are assigning the block with your slideshow to the correct region, and make sure your slideshow has content.

Answer (score 1):

To add a custom region to your theme:

1. in your **subtheme.info** file (or zen.info if you don't have a subtheme...), **declare the new region** in the regions list : `regions[featured_slider] = Featured slider`.
2. in your `page.tpl.php`, render the region content

   ```
   <?php if ($page['featured_slider']): ?>
     <div id="featured-slider">
       <?php print render($page['featured_slider']); ?>
     </div> <!-- End Featured Slider-->
   <?php endif; ?>
   ```

   Don't forget to **empty your cache**.
3. Last step : assign your block to the new region, from `admin/structure/block` admin menu, or with

   ```
   $block = module_invoke('views', 'block_view', 'SLIDESHOW_VIEWBLOCK_NAME'); 
   print render($block);
   ```

(I would personnally not create a region just for a slideshow and put it in the header region, but it's up to you of course.)

Answer (score 0):

You can alternatively not change any php and just assign your slideshow block to the Content region (at the top) so its above your normal page content, and therefore below your navigation (menu).